# Abrir una ventana modal de bootstrap con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo una función en JavaScript que hace una validación de datos. El problema es que usa `alerts` para advertir cuando están mal cargados los datos. Lo que quiero hacer es que muestre ventanas modales de Bootstrap para ver el error.

Esto es lo que hice, que no funciona:

```
var contador = <?=($_GET['sensores'])? count($_GET['sensores']):'0'?>;
    window.validar = function (cual){
        if(cual.value == -1){

        }
        if($("#muestragrafico1").is(':checked')){
            var cantidad = 3;
        }else{
            var cantidad = 1;
        }
        if(cual.checked){
            contador++;
        }else{
            contador--;
        }
        if(contador <= cantidad){
            return true;
        }else{
            if (cantidad == 3) {
                //alert("Solo puede seleccionar un máximo de "+cantidad+" sensores.");
                $('#myModalExito').modal('show');

            }

            if (cantidad == 1) {
                alert("Solo puede seleccionar un máximo de "+cantidad+" sensores.");
            }
            contador--;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿lo quieres hacer usando javascript puro?

Comment: ¿Cuales errores te aparecen al inspeccionar el elemento?

Comment: Deberia o embeberlo en la funcíon ya existente alguna forma.

Comment: No me aparece ningun error, simplemente no muestra la ventana modal. El bootstrap esta correcamente cargado y se usa en otras partes de la pagina y no da problemas.  El unico problema es al tratar de llamar a la ventana modal desde esa funcion js, porque ignora la linea del llamado y lo he probado de muchas formas pero de ninguna he conseguido que lo haga.

Comment: mmm pareciera como si nunca estuviera entrando a la condicion donde se muestra el modal, ¿has intentado con un console.log o algo parecido?

Comment: si cambio la ventana modal, por un alert funciona correctamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51610/discussion-between-sinaxtis-and-rene-limon).

Answer (score 9):

Ésto está mal y debería darte un error:

```
mE.function.modal();
```

Para abrir y cerrar modales de bootstrap programáticamente, se hace desde su misma API por medio de jQuery:

```
$('#myModalExito').modal('show'); // abrir
$('#myModalExito').modal('hide'); // cerrar
```

Comment: Probe de esa forma y tampoco funciona

Comment: Según la [API oficial](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api) de Bootstrap es la forma correcta. Si no te funciona, es que hay otra cosa. ¿Ya miraste la consola si hay errores?

Comment: no hay errores, yo creo que como la funcion es js puro y no jquery no me deja llamarlo de esa forma pero no estoy seguro
la verdad tengo experiencia casi nula en js, me dedico a php y casi nunca he tocado js

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="myModalExito" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo L::Ticket_Succes?></h4> </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>